# Compare strings in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to check if a string exists in another string using lisp. I tried the following:

```
    (string<=  "walk" "wall")
```

and it gives: "3"

What i need to do is to check if the whole string in the left hand side (^walk) is in the right hand side (not the substrings), so for the previous example it should give false and with :

```
    (string<=  "walk" "walk on")
```

it should be true or "4".

Any help please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to Google for the lisp search function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, you're looking for a string-prefix. The Common Lisp idiom for that is `(string= pattern haystack :end2 (length pattern))`.

Answer (score 6):

In SBCL Common Lisp

```
(search "walk" "wall") -> NIL
(search "walk" "walk on") -> 0
```

Thus `0` indicates the index of the first match. If you wanted the end of the first match you could do

```
(let ((pat "walk"))
  (+ (length pat) (search pat "walk on"))) -> 4
```

Comment: Thank you. What if i don't want it to match (search "walk" "hi walk on")?

Comment: @MahmoudGZAWI you can't stop it matching but you can just check whether the match index is =0.

Comment: If you only want to match the beginning, it would be more efficient to use `(STRING= S1 S2 :END2 (LENGTH S1))` because `SEARCH` will search through the whole string.